# Unable to access the html file in template folder of spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

html files are placed under resources/templates/login.html directory of spring boot application(show in the screenshot), deployed it in the weblogic server and when I try to access the login.html with the below URL, it gives The webpage cannot be found message

http://localhost:7001/demo/login.html

below is the screenshot

[image]

In one of the post I found the below code snippet and tried, but it didn't work

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

I am not getting what mistake I did, Could some one help me regarding this ...?

Comment: How did you map 'demo' to your static/templates folder? Did you try to access your html via 'localhost:7001/static/templates/login.html'

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner, yes i tried it gives 404 error

Comment: Can you try to move static folder to one level above (next to resources)?

Comment: is it not a standard to put all html files into resources/ templates folder in spring boot

Comment: Here it says, spring by default serves files from /META-INF/resources/,
/resources/,
/static/,
/public/
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: please tell me where should I move the templates folder ?

Comment: To src/main folder so that your templates will be in src/main/static/templates/login.html

Comment: moved to src/main folder , now its src/main/java/resources/templates/login.html but no success

Comment: How did you try to access the file?

Comment: http://localhost:7001/demo/resources/templates/login.html

Comment: Can you try localhost:7001/templates/login.html

Comment: no success , error 404-not found

Comment: Opps, I just realized you said "src/main/java/resources/templates/login.html". Do not put it under java 
 folder. Move it to src/main/resources/templates/login.html and try again

Comment: moved to src/main/resources/templates/login.html and tried with localhost:7001/templates/login.html -- no success 404 error

Comment: Then there must be something else missing from your config or something affecting this. At the beginning of this conversation, you kept adding 'demo' to your urls. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: also tried with http://localhost:7001/resources/templates/login.html, giving same error

Comment: demo is the context path of the application

Answer (score 7):

Spring Boot by default serves all content found under `/static`, `/public`, `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources`, see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content). So all content in your `static` folder should be served well (check that). But the `templates` folder is not a sub-folder of the `static`, so it will not be served. If I get you right, the `templates` is not supposed to be part of the URL path, right? So you could either move your `login.html` to the `static` folder, or you could add the `templates` folder to the classpath resource locations. Either programmatically (as you did for the other locations), or by setting the corresponding property:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/templates/,classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/
```

Comment: added the entry given by you in the application.properties still not working

Comment: moved all the js , html files to the src/main/resources folder still its not working , responding with 404

Comment: Well, I checked all the stuff before I wrote it, so I guess there is another problem. Is there any filtering (e.g. security) involved?

Comment: added spring security in the application with angularjs, when http://localhost:7001/demo/customlogin,  it should direct to the customlogin.html but it is not hapening

Comment: spring.resources.static-locations is deprecated use spring.web.resources.static-locations instead.